# Curve modifier breaks the model

Tags: modifiers

I have created a model of the bridge with separate parts and merged them all together into one with (ctrl + j). Now I am trying to apply a curve modifier to slightly bend the shape of the bridge. I created a path curve and applied the modifier to the bridge model, then, as soon as I start to move the curve the bridge deforms into some unrecognisable shape. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be fixed? Thank you.

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Link to the project file:
[Project file](https://pasteall.org/blend/e51f8a9a83684b73b907288ee1615f4d)

Comment: Hello, maybe share the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, just uploaded the project file; thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Object* mode apply the curve's scale, and, as it will change the vertices' radius, in *Edit* mode select all and in the *N* panel > *Item* > lower the *Mean Radius* down to 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and helping me I would never have figured out what the problem was myself